# How to get the count of a particular category for each year?

Tags: sql, mysql-python

I am trying out a problem which states me to find " For each year, count the number of movies in that year that had only female actors".

Table schema is as follows:

```
--------------------   -----------------------   ----------------------
|   Movie          |   |     Person           |  |       Cast         |
--------------------   ------------------------  ----------------------
| MovieID  | year  |   |  PersonID  | Gender  |  | MovieID | PersonID |
--------------------   ------------------------  ----------------------
```

Running the following query:

```
SELECT M.YEAR, COUNT(M.MID) NUMBER_OF_FEMALE_ONLY_MOVIES FROM MOVIE M 
WHERE M.MID IN (SELECT X.MID FROM (SELECT AX.MID, COUNT(AX.PID) TOTAL_CAST 
FROM M_CAST AX GROUP BY AX.MID) X 
WHERE 
X.TOTAL_CAST = (SELECT COUNT(A.PID) FROM M_CAST A, PERSON B WHERE A.MID = 
X.MID AND
TRIM(B.PID) = TRIM(A.PID) AND B.GENDER = 'Female')) GROUP BY M.YEAR
```

My results are :

```
---------------------------------------
| year | NUMBER_OF_FEMALE_ONLY_MOVIES  |
---------------------------------------
| 1999 |    1                          |
| 2005 |    1                          | 
| 2009 |    1                          |
| 2012 |    1                          |
| 2018 |    1                          |
----------------------------------------
```

But I need to return 0 as count for the years which do not have any such movies.
Eg.

```
2013 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    WITH 
PERSON_CAST_MERGE AS
   (
    SELECT P.PID,C.MID,GENDER
    FROM PERSON P
    INNER JOIN M_CAST C ON C.PID = P.PID
   ),
    MALE_COUNT AS
   (
    SELECT F.MID FROM PERSON_CAST_MERGE F
    WHERE TRIM(F.GENDER) NOT  LIKE "%FEMALE%"
   ),
FEMALE_COUNT AS
   (
    SELECT F.MID FROM PERSON_CAST_MERGE F
    WHERE TRIM(F.GENDER) LIKE "%FEMALE%"
   ),
 ONLY_FEMALE AS
 (
    SELECT F.MID FROM FEMALE_COUNT F
    WHERE F.MID NOT IN (SELECT M.MID FROM MALE_COUNT M)
 ),
 TEST AS
 (
 SELECT M.YEAR,COUNT(M.MID) AS NO_OF_MOVIES
 FROM ONLY_FEMALE F
INNER JOIN MOVIE M ON M.MID = F.MID
GROUP BY M.YEAR
 )

 SELECT M.YEAR,
 CASE  
    WHEN M.YEAR IN (SELECT F.YEAR FROM TEST F) THEN
        (SELECT F.NO_OF_MOVIES FROM TEST F WHERE F.YEAR = M.YEAR)
    WHEN M.YEAR <> (SELECT F.YEAR FROM TEST F) THEN
        0
 END
 AS NO_OF_MOVIES
 FROM MOVIE M
 GROUP BY M.YEAR
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest exploring the data within the CTE to get a better understanding.

First CTE (`all_cast`): Return the entire movie cast

Second CTE (`male_present`): Return movie id's from `all_cast` where there exists male actors.

Result: Return movies from `all_cast` where movie id is not present in `male_present`

```
WITH all_cast AS (
    SELECT SUBSTR(m."year",-4) as 'Year', m.title, trim(m.MID) as MID, p.Name, trim(p.Gender) as Gender  
    FROM Movie m
    JOIN M_Cast mc 
        ON m.MID = mc.MID
    JOIN Person p 
        ON trim(mc.PID) = p.PID
),

male_present AS (
    SELECT year, mid, name
    FROM all_cast
    WHERE Gender = 'Male'
)


SELECT year, COUNT(DISTINCT mid) as 'All Female Cast'
FROM all_cast a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM male_present WHERE a.mid = mid)
GROUP BY year
```

Answer (score 0):

You need only the group by with subquery as you require reference to the movieids of personids with gender as female in person

```
     SELECT YEAR, COUNT(*) FROM 
     MOVIE 
    Where MovieId IN (SELECT MOVIEId 
   from CAST WHERE PERSONID IN 
   (Select PersonId from Person Where 
    Gender ='FEMALE'))
    Group by Year
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be solved by joining all tables and filtering on WHERE clause for female actors. In this case joining tables will also give better performance rather than sub-querying.

Please try the following code:

```
Select year, count(*) 
from movie 
join Cast on movie.movieid = cast.movieid
join person on person.personid = cast.personid
where person.gender = 'Female'
group by year
```

Please let me know if that works fine for you.

Comment: @marc_s Instead of giving the required result for **only female actors** the approach gives result for atleast one female actor

Answer (score 0):

Try this- A DISTINCT MovieID is required as there may have multiple Female casting for a single movie. Distinct will provide the actual count of movies.

```
SELECT 
M.Year,
COUNT(DISTINCT MovieID)  
FROM Movie M
INNER JOIN Cast C ON M.MovieID = C.MovieID
INNER JOIN Person P ON C.PersonID = P.PersonID 
WHERE P.Gender = 'Female'
GROUP BY M.Year;
```

Answer (score 0):

By merging your query with the Movie table using the outer left join, you can get the desired results. The time taken will be very low compared to the answer posted by @Lucky

```sql
WITH FEMALE_ONLY AS
  (SELECT M.YEAR,
          COUNT(M.MID) COUNT_ALL_FEMALE
   FROM MOVIE M
   WHERE M.MID IN
       (SELECT Q.MID
        FROM
          (SELECT MC.MID,
                  COUNT(MC.PID) total
           FROM M_CAST MC
           GROUP BY MC.MID) Q
        WHERE Q.total =
            (SELECT COUNT(A.PID)
             FROM M_CAST A,
                  PERSON B
             WHERE A.MID = Q.MID
               AND TRIM(B.PID) = TRIM(A.PID)
               AND B.Gender = 'Female'))
   GROUP BY M.YEAR)
SELECT DISTINCT M.year,
                coalesce(FO.COUNT_ALL_FEMALE, 0) FEMALE_ONLY_MOVIES
FROM Movie M
LEFT OUTER JOIN FEMALE_ONLY FO ON M.year = FO.year
ORDER BY M.year;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
select z.year, count(*)
from Movie z
where not exists (select *
                  from Person x, M_Cast xy
                  where x.PID = xy.PID and xy.MID = z.MID and x.gender!='Female')
group by z.year;
```